# How to parse text from a single line of xml by using python

Tags: python, regex, xml

I have a single line of xml and would like to parse all text parts into a list of text.

```
text = '<string name="status">Finishing <xliff:g id="number">%d</xliff:g> percent.</string>'
```

My desired output:

```
desired_output = ['Finishing', '%d', 'percent.']
```

I used regular expression for this simple task.

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'>.+<')
match = re.findall(pattern, text)

match = ['>Finishing <xliff:g id="number">%d</xliff:g> percent.<']
```

It seems regular expression failed to get my desired output.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

update your regex to this

```
 pattern = re.compile(r'. *?>(.+?)<')
```

if you are working with xml/html parsing you might consider using [Beautifulsoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/),it will save you a great deal of time to write more regex but if you want to learn regex then it will be by trial and error

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will look into BeautifulSoup